# R compare column values row wise

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with the below structure, and I'd like to create an additional column that compares all column values row wise based on certain criteria i.e M==1 and all other columns == 0

how can I write code using dplyr or otherwise to perform this type of operation row wise across a large dataset?

```
      M     B     L     H
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     0
2     0     1     0     0
3     1     0     0     0
4     0     1     0     0
5     0     0     1     0
6     0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `map/reduce` on the rest of the columns to check if all them are 0 and then do a `&` with `M == 1`

```
library(dplyr)# 1.0.0
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(flag = M == 1 & select(., -M) %>% 
                              map(., `==`, 0) %>%
                              reduce(`&`))
#  M B L H  flag
#1 1 0 0 0  TRUE
#2 0 1 0 0 FALSE
#3 1 0 0 0  TRUE
#4 0 1 0 0 FALSE
#5 0 0 1 0 FALSE
#6 0 0 0 1 FALSE
```

---

Another option is `rowwise` with `c_across` (from `dplyr >= 1.0`) (but it could be slower)

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(new = all(c_across(B:H) == 0) & M == 1)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Rowwise: 
#      M     B     L     H new  
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
#1     1     0     0     0 TRUE 
#2     0     1     0     0 FALSE
#3     1     0     0     0 TRUE 
#4     0     1     0     0 FALSE
#5     0     0     1     0 FALSE
#6     0     0     0     1 FALSE
```

---

The `map/reduce` is similar to `base R` option with `lapply/Reduce` where we loop over the columns of the dataset with `lapply` (here `df1[-1]` as we don't want to use first column i.e. 'M'), create a `list` of logical `vector`s with `==`,

```
lapply(df1[-1], `==`, 0)
#$B
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

#$L
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

#$H
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

then `Reduce` the `list` to a single logical vector with `&` by comparing the corresponding `list` element positions i.e. if all of them are `TRUE`, it returns TRUE

```
Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[-1], `==`, 0))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and then append with `M == 0`

```
df1$M == 0 & Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[-1], `==`, 0))
```

---

Or another option in `base R` is `rowSums`

```
df1$M == 1 & !rowSums(df1[-1] != 0)
```

Or can also be written as

```
df1$M == 1 & rowSums(df1[-1] == 0) == ncol(df1[-1])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(M = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), L = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), H = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: this works very well, thank you! could you please explain how the map and reduce functions are working, so I can understand how to build on this?

Comment: @ErikRasmussen added some explanations.  Hope it helps